# Submenu missing from Windows 10 Search

Tags: search, menu, system-administration

I recently upgrade Windows 10 from 1903 to 1909, I found the submenu in the Windows has changed like below.

[Comparison between 2 systems on 1909 and 1903](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU0F2.png)

Is this expected? or is this related to some System Settings?

PS: I checked the UAC config. Both are the same level: "Default - Always notify me when ..."

Comment: During the updating period, I also upgraded Microsoft Edgy from the Legacy to new Edgy built on Chrome core. I ruled out this for causing the issue as I did a test on a brand new installation, the submenu were not impacted.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.

I overwrite installed Windows 10 1909. It took almost 24 hours. 
The re-installation has fixed many small issues as well.

A guess was the recent Windows Update had broken many basic functions, re-installation has updated/overwritten the broken files then fixed the issues.